# how to check variable null and if it's array then check lenght

Tags: javascript

```
let abc = null;
```

but down some where in code it is assigned with array object,
I have a variable,
some time it return null and sometime it is an array, How i can check that condition.

My code -

```
if (!abc) {
            status = labels.not_applicable;
        }
```

in this case when array comes in abc it doesn't work.
when abc is array and length is zero this code is not working,

Comment: try `!abc || !abc.length`

Comment: if you are sure it will return array then initialized it with blank array. and use length to handle the condition

Comment: I am not sure if it will be array.

Comment: _"some time it return null and sometime it is an array"_ - Why? Just do `abc = []` and only check the `.lenght`

Answer (score 1):

Handle like this.

```
if((Array.isArray(abc) && abc.length ==0) || !abc){
  status = labels.not_applicable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this OR condition. This will surely help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var a = null

if(!a){
document.write("null")
}

a = []
//use this condition only
if(!a || a.length == 0){
document.write("\nhello")
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if abc is null or abc is an array with 0 length.

If true then set the status as not applicable.

```
if (abc === null || abc.length === 0) {
    status = labels.not_applicable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically check with strict `===`

```
if (abc === null) {
    // Do something
}
```

If you want to allow `undefined` you can use `==`.

If you want to check is an array or not, then it's better to use `Array.isArray(abc)`.

P.S. `Array` in JS is truthy no matter if it is empty or containing any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.isArray()` method to confirm that a variable declared is an array, here's an example of its implementation:

```js
abc = ["",""]

if(abc && Array.isArray(abc)){
    console.log("I am an array")
}
```